# In Pandas, how to assign a function manipulating strings on a column?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create/modify a column by applying a function manipulating strings from one or two columns.

To give a concrete example, I have the following dataframe and function:

```py
def get_sign(number:str, name:str) -> str:
    """Function to apply on two columns to produce another one"""
    if number.startswith("-"):
        return "Negative-" + name[0]
    else:
        return "Positive-" + name[0]

df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ["John", "Jack", "Jeff", "Kate"], "number":["123_456", "-123", "+456", "-0"], "age": [10, 20, 30, 36]})
```

I am trying to get this Dataframe:

```
    name    number  age sign
0   John    123_456 10  Positive-J
1   Jack    -123    20  Negative-J
2   Jeff    +456    30  Positive-J
3   Kate    -0      36  Negative-K
```

I tried to use `assign` with Series transformed to "strings" but got the following errors:

```
df.assign(sign=lambda x:get_sign(x["number"].str, x["name"].str))
```

```
<ipython-input-64-e72c1bf8f4bf> in <lambda>(x)
      7 
      8 df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ["John", "Jack", "Jeff", "Kate"], "number":["123_456", "-123", "+456", "-0"], "age": [10, 20, 30, 36]})
----> 9 df.assign(sign=lambda x:get_sign(x["number"].str, x["name"].str))
     10 df["sign"] = pd.Series([get_sign(el) for el in df["number"]])
     11 df
 
...

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

How can I achieve it? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your function , you can try:

```
def get_sign(number:str, name:str) -> str:
    """Function to apply on two columns to produce another one"""
    if number.startswith("-"):
        return "Negative-" + name[0]
    else:
        return "Positive-" + name[0]
out = df.assign(sign=df[['number','name']].apply(lambda x: get_sign(*x),axis=1))
```

Note that you can vectorize the function too so that you dont need `apply` which is slow:

```
import numpy as np
def get_sign_modified(dataframe,number:str, name:str) -> str:
    return np.where(dataframe[number].str.startswith("-"),
    "Negative-" + dataframe[name].str[0], "Positive-" +dataframe[name].str[0])
out = df.assign(sign=get_sign_modified(df,'number','name'))
```

---

```
   name   number  age        sign
0  John  123_456   10  Positive-J
1  Jack     -123   20  Negative-J
2  Jeff     +456   30  Positive-J
3  Kate       -0   36  Negative-K
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the tip on how to vectorize the function: this is something I was thinking of, but cannot do at the moment because the functions shall also be used on some simple strings elsewhere in the program (although it might change).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the optimal solution but this could work

1. Using columns as `Series`
2. Looping all elements, zipped
3. Applying the function on these elements

This leads to such line of code:

```py
df["sign"] = pd.Series([get_sign(nb, name) for nb, name in zip(df["number"], df["name"])])
```